# How to append several rows to an existing pandas dataframe with number of rows depending on a comprehension list

Tags: python, pandas, append, intervals

I am trying to fill an exisiting dataframe in pandas by adding several rows at one time, the number of rows depend on a comprehension list so it is variable. The initial dataframe is filled as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import portion as P

columns = ['chr', 'Start', 'End', 'type']
x = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

RANGE = [(212, 222),(866, 888),(152, 158)]

INTERVAL= P.Interval(*[P.closed(x, y) for x, y in RANGE])

def fill_df(df, junction, chr, type ):
    
    df['Start'] = [x.lower for x in junction]
    df['End'] =  [x.upper for x in junction]
    df['chr'] = chr
    df['type'] = type

    return df

z = fill_df(x, INTERVAL, 1, 'DUP')
```

The idea is to keep appending rows to the dataframe from different intervals (so variable number of rows). Append those rows to the existing dataframe.

[Here](https://thispointer.com/python-pandas-how-to-add-rows-in-a-dataframe-using-dataframe-append-loc-iloc/) I have found different ways to add several rows but none of them are easy to apply unless I wrote a function to convert my data in tupples or lists, which I am not sure if it would be efficient. I have also try with pandas append but I was not able to do it for a bunch of lines..

Is it there any simple way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the list comprehension in pd.Series?

`df['Start.pos'] = pd.Series([x.lower for x in junction])`

Comment: Sorry I might have not explained well myself, once I get the dataframe I want to keep adding rows to the same dataframe basing in other intervals. And I dont know how to append the new rows. The problem is with  appending rows to the ones already given.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use append and append several elements at once, you can create a second DataFrame table and simply append it to the first one. This looks like this:

```
import intvalpy as ip
import pandas as pd

inf = [1, 2, 3]
sup = [4, 5, 6]

intervals = ip.Interval(inf, sup)
add_intervals = ip.Interval([-10, -20], [10,20])

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'start': intervals.a, 'end': intervals.b})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'start': add_intervals.a, 'end': add_intervals.b})

df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
print(df.head(10))
```

The intvalpy library specialized for classical and full interval arithmetic is used here. To set an interval or intervals, use the Interval function, where the first argument is the left end and the second is the right end of the intervals.
The ignore_index parameter allows to continue indexing of the first table.

In case you want to add one line, you can do it as follows:

```
for k in range(len(intervals)):
    df = df.append({'start': intervals[k].a, 'end': intervals[k].b}, ignore_index=True)

print(df.head(10))
```

I purposely did it with a loop to show that you can do without creating a second table if you want to add a few rows.